# Calling Python code in Swift Callback from Python called from Swift

Tags: python, swift, ffi, swift-pythonkit

Pardon the confusing title but I am doing something truly cursed.

I have a large project written in Python that I want to write a GUI in Swift for. I'm able to use PythonKit to call my Python code from Swift just fine.

The only problem is that the Python program deals with laying out the UI elements since they form a directed graph and the layout algorithm is non-trivial.

The layout algorithm needs to know the size of each node in the graph to deal with overlapping nodes, but only the GUI knows what the rendered size of each node will be.

Therefore, I want to pass a callback written in Swift to the layout function that is written in Python.

I've pared down the code to be able to minimally reproduce the behavior.

```
let nodeSizeFn: @convention(c) (UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = { _ in
    return PyInt_FromLong(30)
}

let nodeSizeFnPtr = unsafeBitCast(nodeSizeFn, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self)
let nodeSizeFnAddr = UInt(bitPattern: nodeSizeFnPtr)

private let ctypes = Python.import("ctypes")
let sizefn = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.py_object)(nodeSizeFnAddr)

let (xs, ys, ws, hs) = graph.layout(sizefn).tuple4
```

This code segfaults in the call to `PyInt_FromLong` in the callback. From using LLDB, it seems that the `SMALL_INT` singleton/global object/static object (in CPython parlance) is null in the callback. I'm not sure how this is possible since PythonKit calls `Py_Initialize` and a similar call to `PyInt_FromLong` outside of the callback works fine.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Post a [mre]. Anyway, you are misunderstanding the ```ctypes.CFUNCTYPE()```. See [Callback functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions). Also why are you using the ```ctypes```, instead of the ```PythonFunction``` API? See [this](https://github.com/pvieito/PythonKit/blob/v0.4.1/PythonKit/Python.swift#L1596).

Comment: I see now that I was misunderstanding `CFUNCTYPE`. I also somehow missed `PythonFunction`, thanks for pointing me to it. It's what I was looking for. I was using `ctypes` because I couldn't figure out how to create a Python callable from a function pointer. Anyways, if you want the points, you can post your comment as an answer

Comment: Why not answer your own question?

Comment: @relent95 Likely so that he can give you the credit and reward your insight.

Comment: @genghiskhan, you can have my credit.